# Micrometer and Prometheus Timer as Rate

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

According to Micrometer's documentation https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_server_side, the framework (Micrometer) should handle converting the timer metric to a rate from absolute amount

The below code simulates a dummy timer:

```
@Service
public class AppService {
    private Timer timer = Metrics.timer("foobar");

    public String test() {
        timer.record(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

However in Prometheus I see only monotonically increasing metrics `foobar_seconds_sum` and `foobar_seconds_count` instead of seeing them as rates

[image]

Perhaps I misunderstood or overlooked something in the documentation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is how a Prometheus Summary works, you can calculate the average event size with:

```
  rate(foobar_seconds_sum[5m])
/
  rate(foobar_seconds_count[5m])
```

With Prometheus client libraries are dumb, and should leave more complex math to Prometheus.

Comment: thank you, that makes way more sense. this proves that my understanding of the documentation was reversed somehow. answer accepted

Comment: why `rate`, perhaps `increase` is a better fit?

Comment: They'd both return the same result as you're dividing, rate is the usual and more succinct way to do this.